# how to create an informatica flat file with dynamic name and trailer

Tags: unix, informatica

I am creating a dynamic name flat file in informatica powercenter. I have to accomplish two tasks: create a flat file with timestamp appended to it's name, and also append a trailer having the record count to the flat file. I am able to perform the above two tasks separately but i am not sure how i can accomplish them together. If i create a flat file with timestamp info using informatica file name port and use a unix script in a command task to append the trailer how can i refer to the variable file name in my unix script. I am using the following command to refer to the output file name generated by informatica:

```
file='ls output_file.txt'
```

here the name of output file is not variable. I wanted to know how can i call an output file with a variable name in this command or the script itself.Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create workflow variable, e.g. $$TargetFileName
2. Create an `Assignment Task` and assign the desired name to the variable, e.g. `'output_file_' || TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP(), 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS') || '.txt'`
3. Use a post-session command (e.g. `wc -l < $$TargetFileName >> $$TargetFileName`) to add the line count to the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach

1. Create a FileName variable in Expression.
2. 'Filename_'||to_char(PERSON_ID)||'_'||to_char(sessstarttime, 'MM-DD-YYYY_HH24miss')||'.txt'

I added the PERSON_ID to add another ID unique identifier but its an option